# Changing color character text of a JLabel?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I'm trying changing color character text of a JLabel.

I have a `JLabel` with text: "JLABEL" and I want change only color character "L". After to change, I want display text "JLABEL" with character "L" changed.

How can I do this ?

I'm trying this:

```
private void characterFormat(){  
    jlabel.setText("JLABEL");
    char[] t = jlabel.getText().toCharArray();
    String txtFormat = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < t.length; x++){
        if(t[x] == 'L'){
            txtFormat += String.format("<html><font color=RED>%s</font></html>", t[x]);
        }
    }        
    jlabel.setText(txtFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correct. To just change a JLables text and highlighting the 'L' Character in red you can do the following:

```
String text = jlabel.getText(); 
text = "<html><body>" + text.replaceAll("L", "<span style=\"color:red\">L</span>") + "</body></html>";
jlabel.setText(text);
```